# VBA Code quit working in Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word

I don't know why, but this code has suddenly stopped working and I am looking for help in finding the reason why.

```
PictCount = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count  ' This always returns 0
PageCount = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count  ' This gives the correct number
```

This is on a page that several pictures have been copied/pasted onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A picture is not seen as a shape when it is inlined with the text. If it floats over, underneath or between the text, then it is counted as a shape. So, right-click the picture, choose 'Wrap text', and then any other option than 'Inline with text', and you should see the number increasing.

As a counterpart, there's also `InlineShapes`, which contains those inlined pictures, and not the floating pictures.
So adding them up should give you all pictures together.

```
PictCount = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count + ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
```

Comment: Ok, that sounds good. Is there a way to make all pictures pasted default to something other than "Inline with text"?

Comment: In Word 2010 (2007 as well I believe) choose File, Word Options, the Advanced Tab. In the 'Cut, copy & paste' section change 'Insert/paste pictures as' to something other than 'In line with text'. This will change the default paste-behaviour.